# Fetching data only for specified mapping in HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have following `hbm.xml` file

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
      <class catalog="test_user" name="test.user" table="user">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
          <column name="id"/>
          <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
          <column length="200" name="name" unique="true"/>
        </property>

    <set fetch="join" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="education" table="user_education">
          <key>
            <column name="aid"/>
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="test.UserEducation"/>
        </set>
<set fetch="join" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="employment" table="user_employment">
          <key>
            <column name="aid"/>
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="test.UserEmployment"/>
        </set>
<set fetch="join" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="otherProfiles" table="user_other_profile">
          <key>
            <column name="aid"/>
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="test.OtherProfile"/>
        </set>
<set fetch="join" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="settings" table="user_setting">
          <key>
            <column name="aid"/>
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="test.Setting"/>
        </set>
<set fetch="join" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="images" table="user_images">
          <key>
            <column name="aid"/>
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="test.Images"/>
        </set>
 ..
..
...
```

and many tables associate with user here I am using `fetch="join"`
 for maximum tables.
In other queries I have to fetch data from few other related tables so I made
`fetch="join"`.

I want to execute quest

```
from user as u
left join fetch u.settings
where u.id=25
```

My problem is when I want to fetch data from user it always fetch data from all associated table where `fetch="join"`.
I want to know how to fetch only related join data. For above query only data from user and settings data should be fetched not from other tables when we have specified  `fetch="join"` for multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use fetch="join" because [EAGER fetching can lead to Cartesian Products and it's not very efficient](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).

You need to set those associations to `lazy="true"` and only fetch themon a query basis:

```
from user as u
left join fetch u.settings
where u.id=25
```

This way, you will only fetch Users along with their settings and without join fetching the other associations.

Comment: what should be the fetch value ??

Comment: The `fetch` attribute should be removed, if that's what you are asking. This way it will default to `fetch="select"`, which you then override with the query-time fetch directives.

Comment: So in case of join also select is best option ?